# Store excel string data to an Array list

Tags: java, excel, string, arraylist, apache-poi

I need to store excel cell data to an array list. I've managed to get the cell data as 2 strings (data of two columns). Now I need to store the string data to array list (or two). My code is as follows:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheetAt(0);

int  i;
for (i=0; i <= sh.getLastRowNum(); i++)

    {

XSSFRow r = sh.getRow(i);

//Data from first column.
String col1 = r.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();

//Data from second column.
double col2 = r.getCell(1).getNumericCellValue();
}
```

Now I need to store them (`col1` and `col2`) into array list. How can this be done? I need to use this array to write the data into seperate sheet later.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your second column data looks to be a Double data type. Do you want to keep that data type within the ArrayList?

Comment: Yes col1 is a String and col2 is Double.

Comment: You could do it this way: Above the **for** loop: `List<List<Object>> listOfRows = new ArrayList<>(); List<Object> listOfColValues;` Then inside the **for** loop: `listOfColValues = new ArrayList<>(); listOfColValues.add(col1); listOfColValues.add(col2); listOfRows.add(listOfColValues);` And to obtain the data from the 2D List Interface Array: `for (int i = 0; i < listOfRows.size(); i++) { String col1Data = listOfRows.get(i).get(0).toString(); double col2Data = (double) listOfRows.get(i).get(1); System.out.println(col2Data + "  -  " + col2Data); }`

Comment: There is a mistake in the code within the above comment. The `System.out.println(col2Data + " - " + col2Data);` **should really be:** `System.out.println(col1Data + " - " + col2Data);`.  :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `List data = new ArrayList()`, but when you'll be trying to get data from this list you'll need to cast each object to `String` or `double` which can be unsafe, if you'll be inserting new values you'll get a warning about raw type. In your case maybe consider using `Map<String, Double>`, it'll be more safe and natural.